# Search through the database using a combobox, if an item is in a database, prompt will appear

Tags: vb.net

Good day everyone.

I'm making a POS and Inventory Management System and I'm having a problem with this particular module as of now.

When adding an item to purchase order list, if an item is already in the purchaseorder database, the system will prompt that there is already a pending order. I've done the prompt, but the adding to the database was kinda messed up. It doesn't do a thing at all. The code there is working when I remove the ds.hasrows and while dr.read conditions. This is my code:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Ceiling = CInt(txtCeiling.Text)
    TotalQuantity = CurrentItemQuantity + CInt(txtPurchaseQty.Text)

    If TotalQuantity > Ceiling Then
        MsgBox("Exceeds Ceiling Point.")
    Else

        sqlString = "SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM posinventory.purchaseorder WHERE purchaseorder.PRODUCT_ID = '" & cboProductID.Text & "'"

        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlString, con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read

                If CurrentItem = dr.Item("PRODUCT_ID") Then

                    MsgBox("Product has pending order.")
                    cboProductID.Focus()

                Else

                    sqlString = "INSERT INTO posinventory.purchaseorder (PRODUCT_ID, PURCHASE_QUANTITY, DATE_PURCHASED, TIME_PURCHASED) VALUES (" & cboProductID.Text & ", '" & txtPurchaseQty.Text & "', '" & txtDate.Text & "', '" & txtTime.Text & "')"

                    Try
                        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlString, con)
                        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        dr.Close()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox("Error saving to database. Error is: " & ex.Message)
                        Exit Sub
                    End Try

                    MsgBox("Transaction Complete.")

                    lvOrderList.Items.Clear()

                    sqlString = "SELECT posinventory.purchaseorder.TRANSACTION_ID, posinventory.products.PRODUCT_ID, posinventory.products.PRODUCT_NAME, posinventory.products.SUPPLIER_NAME, posinventory.purchaseorder.PURCHASE_QUANTITY, posinventory.purchaseorder.DATE_PURCHASED, posinventory.purchaseorder.TIME_PURCHASED FROM posinventory.purchaseorder, posinventory.products WHERE posinventory.purchaseorder.PRODUCT_ID = posinventory.products.PRODUCT_ID"
                    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlString, con)
                    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    ds = New DataSet
                    da.Fill(ds, "Table")

                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    Dim j As Integer = 0

                    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                            itemcol(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
                        Next

                        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcol)
                        Me.lvOrderList.Items.Add(lvi)
                    Next

                    grpCreateOrder.Enabled = False
                    grpOrderList.Enabled = True
                    cboProductID.SelectedIndex = -1
                    txtPurchaseQty.Text = ""
                    txtDate.Text = ""
                    txtTime.Text = ""
                    txtProductName.Text = ""
                    txtSupplier.Text = ""
                    txtQty.Text = ""
                    txtCeiling.Text = ""
                    btnBack.Enabled = True

                End If

            End While

        End If

        dr.Close()

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are inside of a loop using a cmd and dr. While you are in there you are then defining a new cmd and dr.

Try using different names eg cmd2, dr2.